# Weird CUDA Wrong Output

Tags: c++, cuda

I guess I am not understanding something very critical here. The following code is trying to compute the convolution of two signals using the FFT method. The problem I am having is that sometimes I get a wrong/weird output. When I try and explicitly run each step of my convolution function (at line 104) in main, it works. Now, if I run the code normally, via the convolution function, it works! After I get the output I expect, I cannot recreate the setting that gets me the wrong answer. I am at a loss as to how this could happen.

EDIT - Code block contains data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuda.h>

typedef enum signaltype {REAL, COMPLEX} signal;

typedef float2 Complex;

void
printData(Complex *a, int size, char *msg) {

  if (msg == "") printf("\n");
  else printf("%s\n", msg);

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%f %f\n", a[i].x, a[i].y);
}

void
normData(Complex *a, int size, float norm) {

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i].x /= norm;
    a[i].y /= norm;
  }
}

// flag = 1 for real signals.
void
randomFill(Complex *h_signal, int size, int flag) {

  // Real signal.
  if (flag == REAL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      h_signal[i].x = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
      h_signal[i].y = 0;
    }
  }
}

// FFT a signal that's on the _DEVICE_.
void
signalFFT(Complex *d_signal, int signal_size) {

  // Handle type used to store and execute CUFFT plans.
  // Essentially allocates the resouecwes and sort of interns
  // them.

  cufftHandle plan;
  if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, signal_size, CUFFT_C2C, 1) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to plan FFT\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  // Execute the plan.
  if (cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *) d_signal, (cufftComplex *) d_signal, CUFFT_FORWARD) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    printf ("Failed Executing FFT\n");
    exit(0);
  }

}


// Reverse of the signalFFT(.) function.
void
signalIFFT(Complex *d_signal, int signal_size) {

  cufftHandle plan;
  if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, signal_size, CUFFT_C2C, 1) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Failed to plan IFFT\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  if (cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *) d_signal, (cufftComplex *) d_signal, CUFFT_INVERSE) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {
    printf ("Failed Executing FFT\n");
    exit(0);
  }
}


// Pointwise Multiplication Kernel.
__global__ void
pwProd(Complex *signal1, int size1, Complex *signal2, int size2) {

  int threadsPerBlock, blockId, globalIdx;

  threadsPerBlock = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;
  blockId = blockIdx.x + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x);
  globalIdx = (blockId * threadsPerBlock) + threadIdx.x + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x);

  if (globalIdx <= size1) {

      signal1[globalIdx].x = (signal1[globalIdx].x * signal2[globalIdx].x - signal1[globalIdx].y * signal2[globalIdx].y);
      signal1[globalIdx].y = (signal1[globalIdx].x * signal2[globalIdx].y + signal1[globalIdx].y * signal2[globalIdx].x);
    }

}

void
cudaConvolution(Complex *d_signal1, int size1, Complex *d_signal2,
                int size2, dim3 blockSize, dim3 gridSize) {

  signalFFT(d_signal1, size1);
  signalFFT(d_signal2, size2);

  pwProd<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_signal1, size1, d_signal2, size2);

  //signalIFFT(d_signal1, size1);

}


int allocateAndPad(Complex **a, int s1, Complex **b, int s2) {

  int oldsize, newsize, i;

  newsize = s1 + s2 - 1;

  while (!((newsize != 0) && !(newsize & (newsize - 1)))) {
    newsize++;
  }

  oldsize = s1;
  *a = (Complex *) malloc(sizeof(Complex) * newsize);
  for (i = oldsize; i < newsize; i++) {
    (*a)[i].x = 0;
    (*a)[i].y = 0;
  }

  oldsize = s2;
  *b = (Complex *) malloc(sizeof(Complex) * newsize);
  for (i = oldsize; i < newsize; i++) {
    (*b)[i].x = 0;
    (*b)[i].y = 0;
  }

  return newsize;
}

int main()
{

  Complex *h1, *h2, *d1, *d2;

  int s1, s2, newsize, i, dim;

  int deviceCount;
  cudaError_t e = cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
  if (e != cudaSuccess) {
    return -1;
  }

  dim = 1;

  s1 = 16;
  s2 = 16;

  for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)  {

      newsize = allocateAndPad(&h1, s1, &h2, s2);

      /*h1 = (Complex *) malloc(sizeof(Complex) * s1);
      h2 = (Complex *) malloc(sizeof(Complex) * s2);
      newsize = 16;*/

      randomFill(h1, s1, REAL);
      randomFill(h2, s2, REAL);

      // Kernel Block and Grid Size.
      const dim3 blockSize(16, 16, 1);
      const dim3 gridSize(newsize / 16 + 1, newsize / 16 + 1, 1);

      printData(h1, newsize, "H Signal 1");
      printData(h2, newsize, "H Signal 2");

      cudaMalloc(&d1, sizeof(Complex) * newsize);
      cudaMalloc(&d2, sizeof(Complex) * newsize);
      cudaMemcpy(d1, h1, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      cudaMemcpy(d2, h2, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      cudaConvolution(d1, newsize, d2, newsize, blockSize, gridSize);

      // Explicit code run below,

      /*signalFFT(d1, newsize);
      cudaMemcpy(h1, d1, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      printData(h1, newsize, "1 FFT");
      cudaMemcpy(d1, h1, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      signalFFT(d2, newsize);
      cudaMemcpy(h2, d2, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      printData(h2, newsize, "2 FFT");
      cudaMemcpy(d2, h2, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      pwProd<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d1, newsize, d2, newsize);

      signalIFFT(d1, newsize);*/

      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      cudaMemcpy(h1, d1, sizeof(Complex) * newsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

      //normData(h1, newsize, newsize);

      printData(h1, newsize, "PwProd");

      free(h1); free(h2);
      cudaFree(d1); cudaFree(d2);

      cudaDeviceReset();
  }

  return 0;
}


EDIT: Required Output Data
0.840188 0.000000
0.394383 0.000000
0.783099 0.000000
0.798440 0.000000
0.911647 0.000000
0.197551 0.000000
0.335223 0.000000
0.768230 0.000000
0.277775 0.000000
0.553970 0.000000
0.477397 0.000000
0.628871 0.000000
0.364784 0.000000
0.513401 0.000000
0.952230 0.000000
0.916195 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 H Signal 2
0.635712 0.000000
0.717297 0.000000
0.141603 0.000000
0.606969 0.000000
0.016301 0.000000
0.242887 0.000000
0.137232 0.000000
0.804177 0.000000
0.156679 0.000000
0.400944 0.000000
0.129790 0.000000
0.108809 0.000000
0.998924 0.000000
0.218257 0.000000
0.512932 0.000000
0.839112 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 PwProd
64.765198 0.000000
-20.097927 72.754028
1.797580 1.074046
-5.184547 7.412243
0.148326 0.121253
-3.457163 3.253345
0.834668 -0.752979
-0.414450 0.328347
-1.268492 0.297919
1.634082 -2.054814
0.542893 0.087469
0.244198 -1.392576
0.680159 -0.110084
0.938037 1.743742
1.318125 -2.269666
-1.448638 1.534995
-0.207152 -0.000000
-1.448638 -1.534995
1.318125 2.269666
0.938037 -1.743742
0.680159 0.110084
0.244198 1.392576
0.542893 -0.087469
1.634082 2.054814
-1.268492 -0.297919
-0.414450 -0.328347
0.834668 0.752980
-3.457164 -3.253347
0.148326 -0.121253
-5.184546 -7.412243
1.797580 -1.074046
-20.097923 -72.754013
```

Bad output has the other half (last 16 rows) of the pwprod as just H Signal 2 data without the padding.

Comment: I guess you didn't pay attention [when I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781653/cuda-inverse-fft-bug) that you use `cufftComplex` instead and also suggested that you post the actual data as well as what you expect the data to be.  Nobody knows what you mean by "wierd/wrong".

Comment: I'm sorry. I have added those now.

Comment: The thing is, the cuda samples that come with the 5.0 toolkit seem to use Complex with no problem. I doubt if this was the problem but I will change it once I get the code running properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on all cuda API calls and kernel calls (you already have error checking on cufft API calls).

Another useful tool is `cuda-memcheck`.  When I run your code through cuda-memcheck, I get a number of errors, the first of which is pointing at your kernel `pwProd`:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8
=========     at 0x00000088 in pwProd(float2*, int, float2*, int)
=========     by thread (0,2,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x400200300 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libcuda.so (cuLaunchKernel + 0x3dc) [0xc9edc]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 [0xf513]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.5.0 (cudaLaunch + 0x183) [0x30f13]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 [0x13e1]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 (__gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2d2) [0xdea]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 (__gxx_personality_v0 + 0x2fd) [0xe15]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 [0x108b]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 [0x1322]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf4) [0x1d994]
=========     Host Frame:./t171 (__gxx_personality_v0 + 0x51) [0xb69]
```

Then I noticed that kernel thread check looks like this:

```
if (globalIdx <= size1) {
```

I think it should be like this:

```
if (globalIdx < size1) {
```

When I make that change, all the cuda-memcheck errors go away.